# Where does console.writeline output in a webservice go to?

Tags: .net

Where does console.writeline output in a webservice go to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nowhere, unless you call [`Console.SetOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) and tell it where to go.

Answer (score 1):

It's very helpful when you try to debug your WebService, but when not in debug mode, it doesn't go anywhere. Unless, like @marcc said, you tell it where to go.